# UI Bootstrap modal window 'jumping out' of the angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use UI Bootstrap's modal dialog, inside an Angular controller, rendered inside an Asp MVC View.

Somewhere within the page, I embed modal div :

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="newActivityModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

which is triggered by:

```
<button ng-disabled="vm.activityInputText.length == 0" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newActivityModal">
```

So the structure of the page is :

```
<!-- ng-module="xxx" -->
...
   <!-- ng-controller="zzz" -->
   ...
       <!-- button triggering modal -->
       ....
           <!-- modal -->
```

The problem however is that when the page renders, the modal window div 'jumps out' of the div where it originaly was (inside the controller) and appears at the very bottom of the page, right before the body tag.
Since inside the modal I'm using {{}} bound to controller's scope, it breaks.

Am I doint this right ? 
Funny fact : if I instead put this all (the controller, button, modal window etc.) inside an `<ng-view>` it works fine and modal stays where it was in the DOM.

Comment: UI Bootstrap wont sit well with angularjs. Thats why most use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: thank you for the hint ! I've just rewritten the modal window to bootstrap-angular and all my troubles are gone :) If you write it again as a post comment, I can mark as solution